# Get Specific MKAnnotation From Selector

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm implementing a `MKMapView` in an app, and have implemented the `-mapView: viewForAnnotation:` method in order to show dynamically placed pins with callouts on the map. The annotations on the map I'm interested in are defined in a separate class called `Annotation` that implements `MKAnnotation`. In the `-mapView: viewForAnnotation:` method, I need to get the value of the variable which is fed in through the method's `annotation` variable, which will be an instance of `Annotation`.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    return nil;
}

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {
    static NSString *identifier = @"RemoteLocation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    //HERE, I NEED TO GET THE VALUE OF annotation's VARIABLE IN ORDER TO ASSIGN THE ANNOTATIONVIEW IMAGE
    //annotationView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:annotation.senderPhotoURL]]];
    return annotationView;
    }
return nil;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to get the value of the variable from `annotation`, which is an instance of `Annotation`, the variable isn't accessible. What do I need to do to inform the program that `annotation` is an instance of `Annotation`, so that the variable is available to read?

Comment: Did you make sure that you included the Annotation.h in your implementation file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have proved that `annotation` is an `Annotation` underneath you need to cast it to an actual instance of Annotation, like this:

```
Annotation* yourAnnotation = (Annotation *)annotation;
```

Then you can use `yourAnnotation` as you'd expect.